# Eclipse RCP : Outline view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

A simple question. My Outline view in eclipse does not show me the popup-menu which contains the function(copy-paste-delete-....).I add the method :

```
public Object getAdapter(Class required) {}
```

to link my custom editor with the Outline View (and it's work), the content is displayed on this view , but i can't access to the popup-menu to edit this content.

Comment: It is up to you to write the code for the outline context menu.

Comment: I didn't succeed to display the popmenu , I just want help to display a single command; after I'll code the following

Comment: Solved :
plugin.xml<---

<extension
       id="popupMenus"
       point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
    <viewerContribution
          id="myproduct.view.breakpoint"
          targetID="myproduct.ui.views.breakpoint">

        <action
             class="texteditor.DeleteAction"
             enablesFor="+"
             icon="icons/delete_16.png"
             id="com.uanatol.plugin.uiproject.texteditor.delete"
             label="Remove X"
             menubarPath="myproduct.ui.views.breakpoint"
             tooltip="Remove X"/>
      
        </viewerContribution>
 </extension>    
--->

Comment: ContentOutline.JAVA<--
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
super.createControl(parent);
TreeViewer treeViewer = getTreeViewer();
MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu");
   menuManager.add(new Separator("myproduct.ui.views.breakpoint"));
 Menu menu = menuManager.createContextMenu (treeViewer.getControl ());
   treeViewer.setContentProvider(new ContentProvider());
   treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
   treeViewer.getControl ().setMenu (menu);
   getSite().registerContextMenu ("myproduct.ui.views.breakpoint", menuManager, treeViewer);
  
}
-->